# Does "selfie" refer to the picture's taker, the picture's poster, or both

Tags: meaning, slang

I'm a middle-aged person who is not up on the latest trends and am not a social media user.  But a few days ago on CNN, the anchors were going on about the latest celebrity "selfie" that had "gone viral."  My first thought, of course, was "why in the #%%^ is this news?" but then I looked at the photo they were showing.  One could see that the subject was not holding a phone or camera, and the photo was clearly taken at a distance of 20 or so feet.  In other words, it was not taken by the subject.  Shouldn't that have made it a "someone-elsie?"  Or better yet, a plain old-fashion "photograph?"

On the other hand, the celeb had posted the pic to his own something-or-other (maybe insta-gram) account.  So is that what made it a selfie?

I read [this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/selfie) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfie).  Each seems to indicate a selfie is taken by the subject, but neither is perfectly clear.

Comment: Note that ' selfie bars' allow people to take pictures from a distance. https://www.google.it/search?q=selfie+bar&biw=768&bih=928&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=xjebVNjcH8n5Uo_Cg5AL&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=selfie+bluetooth++bar&imgrc=Ipfq6qf6lrn4PM%253A%3BGn16ly4VoOLvHM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fg02.s.alicdn.com%252Fkf%252FHT1.0NNFKFbXXagOFbXt%252F200484502%252FHT1.0NNFKFbXXagOFbXt.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.alibaba.com%252Fproduct-detail%252FPortable-selfie-stand-for-iphone-5_1816330629.html%3B600%3B600

Comment: RE: _One could see both of the subject's hands, and the photo was clearly taken at a distance of 20 or so feet_. Some phones have cameras with built-in timers, so the picture might still be a genuine "selfie", even with both arms showing. [("Look, ma, two hands!")](http://www.studiocalico.com/community/studio-chat/topics/66296-how-do-you-take-a-selfie-at-a-distance-with-your-iphone)

Comment: Perhaps a mirror was the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, CNN was mocked for their incorrect use of "selfie". They even show a "selfie" at one point which is clearly just a portrait.

A selfie is nothing more than a picture including yourself, taken by yourself. It can include anything in the background, foreground, etc - so long as you are the one who took it ( and not with a time-delay where the camera is placed in the distance ).

So the phrase "I took a selfie" would mean, "I took a picture of myself".

Similarly, "Check out my selfie" would imply that the picture was taken of me and by me.

Comment: Do you have a link/ source for this mocking of CNN?

Comment: He's likely referring to this hilarious brief bit from HBO's Last Week Tonight With John Oliver a few months back:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHNx2VVDDnE

Answer (score 3):

"Selfie" as defined by the OED is:

> A photograph that one has taken of oneself

So, typically, it is a photo one takes of oneself.

I have, however, noticed that group photos from smartphones where the *owner of the phone* is central to the picture have also gained the "selfie" title, whether or not that person *took* the actual picture.